# Add dictionary values where values are lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{a: ['1', '2'], b: ['3', '4']}
```

How do I implement a code such that the values in the dictionary are added and are sorted by decreasing value order like so:

```
{b : 7, a : 3}
```

Comment: *"name 'a' is not defined"*. Can you show your code and where you are stuck?

Comment: @Austin, you can think of it as a string. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by:

```
d = {'a': ['1', '2'], 'b': ['3', '4']}
d = {value: sum(int(j) for j in key) for value, key in d.items()}
d = sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x:d[x[0]], reverse = True)
d = {key: value for key, value in d}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution I think explains a couple of mistakes that might be tripping you up.

```
testDictionary = {"a": [1, 2], "b": [3, 4]}

def sumDictionaryParts(dictionary):
    for variable in dictionary:
        sumOfValues = sum(dictionary[variable])
        dictionary[variable] = sumOfValues
    return dictionary

print(sumDictionaryParts(testDictionary))
```

I think you meant to make the key of each pair in the dictionary a string with the "" and keep the values as integers, that way you don't have to worry about types.
It also usually helps to make a subroutine when you have a general problem like this, then you can test it with other inputs and make sure it works.

If you're looking for a good website for learning python dictionaries, I used this a couple years back and it's treated me very well :)

**https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp**

Carry on the coding!

Answer (score 0):

if you need an oneliner then

```
sample_dict = {"a": ["1", "2"], "b": ["3", "4"], "c": ["5"]}

sample_dict = {key: sum(map(lambda x: int(x), sample_dict[key])) for key in sample_dict}

sample_dict = {
    key: sample_dict[key]
    for key in sorted(sample_dict, key=sample_dict.get, reverse=True)
}

print(sample_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'b': 7, 'c': 5, 'a': 3}
```

Comment: Have you tested `sample_dict = {"a": ["1", "2"], "b": ["3", "4"], "c": ["5"]}`?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA this is the output for your given sample `{'c': 5, 'b': 7, 'a': 3}` and its looks alright to me.

Comment: *the values in the dictionary are added and are sorted in decreasing order*.OP seems want to sort the value not the key.It should be `{'b': 7, 'c': 5, 'a': 3}`

Comment: op needs to clarify if he needs the dictionary to be sorted by keys or by values. If have sorted it by keys.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this one line code if you want to sorted by the value:

```
d = {'a': ['1', '2'], 'b': ['3', '4'], "c": ["5"]}
r = dict(sorted(map(lambda item: (item[0], sum(map(int, item[1]))), d.items()), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
```

Result:

```
{'b': 7, 'c': 5, 'a': 3}
```